# Can size of workQueue be more than maximumPoolSize?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

We have ThreadPoolExecutor and its initialising looks like:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(maxThreads, maxThreads, 50000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
```

And the value of `maxThreads` is 200, but there comes a time when `queue.size()` > 200. Why can it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `corePoolSize` nor the `maximumPoolSize` determines the size of the pool, it's the size of the `BlockingQueue` that counts.

You using a `LinkedBlockingQueue`, this is based on a linked structure and has a default maximum size of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. It also allows you to change its maximum size using its constructor by passing the required size, like this:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(200);
```

By passing 200 in its constructor, you pool will hold a maximum of 200 tasks

Comment: So who determines the real size of the pool?  The size of `LinkedBlockingQueue`?

Answer (score 0):

`maxThreads` represents the maximum number of pooled threads. 
Your queue size represents the number of enqueued task pending to be executed.

Comment: so doesn't these enqueued tasks pending to be executed are stored in the pool?

Comment: No, you're confusing things. You have a pool of threads that will execute whatever `Runnable` task they find in the `BlockingQueue`. Your task are in the working queue, when a pool's thread becomes available it will poll a pending task and execute it.